# MVC3 razor Confirmationmail

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, razor

I am doing Confirmation mail sent to the register for this i am following with this URL

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2011/12/06/email-confirmation-asp-net-mvc-web-application.aspx#comments

```
but i am getting error like "Unable to connect to the sqlserverdatabase"
```

Comment: can you add your db connection string from your web.config?  maybe blank out password

Comment: in my web.config my connection is   <add name="EmployeeMVCEntities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.EmployeeModel.csdl|res://*/Models.EmployeeModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.EmployeeModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=192.168.1.200;Initial Catalog=EmployeeMVC;User ID=sa;Password=DBserver123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: what the mistake in my web.config?

Comment: Have you tried to connect to that DB using the server explorer in visual studio?

Comment: I am doing MVC3 razor databasefirst so I add the edmx using that i added the database.

Answer (score 0):

To point out the obvious it looks like you cannot access your sql server database.

Try connecting with sql management studio using the same user.  It looks like something is wrong with your permissions or possibly a typo in your connection details.